# table rowspan error html and css

Tags: html, css, html-table

In my table image (left column) is not working. It has default CSS rules (from template) for `tbody`, `td` and `tr`.

[image: screen shot]

I use `div` outside my `table` and I gave all elements new `id` and/or `class` attributes.

The stylesheet specifies `vertical-align:baseline`, but I don't want that.

#### HTML

```html
<div class= "search-result-table">
    <table class="job-search-result">                                               
        <tr class="job-search-result-row">
            <td class="job-search-img" rowspan="4">
                <img class="job-search-image" src="../images/test-img.jpg" alt="company logo"> </td>
            <td class="job-search-job-title"> Job Title</td>
            <td class="job-view" rowspan="4">
            <button type="button" value="view"> View </button>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td class="job-search-compay-name"> Company Name </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td class="job-search-location-date"> Job Location and Date posted</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td class="job-search-job-detail"> <a href="">More about ths job</a></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
```

#### CSS

```css
.job-search-result { border: solid 1px black; font-family: inherit; }
.job-search-result { vertical-align: middle;    }
.job-search-img { width: 25%; } 
.job-search-img img { width: 150px; height: 150px; } 
.job-search-job-title { width: 65%; margin-top: 0em; padding-top: 0em;  }
.job-view { width: 10%; }
```

Comment: Can you post your CSS and try to explain what you want a little better?

Comment: .job-search-result
   {
    border: solid 1px black;
    font-family: inherit; 
   } 
   
    .job-search-result
   {
    vertical-align: middle; 
   }
   
   
   .job-search-img
   {
    width: 25%;
   }
   
   .job-search-img img
   {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
   }
   
   .job-search-job-title
   {
    width: 65%;
    margin-top: 0em;
    padding-top: 0em; 
   }
   
   .job-view
   {
    width: 10%;
   }

Comment: This is my css.... If I run this code like one simple page its working fine. but with my template its inherit css and table is not align.

Comment: Sorry, not very clear. You are saying that it works as expected, except when used with a template? What kind of template?

Comment: Also, it's not clear what exactly is not working. The image? If so, how? The vertical alignment between table cells? And it sounds like you're complaining that when you change the class names, the CSS is no longer applied. So what did you change the class names to and did you change them the same in the HTML and the CSS?

Comment: Can you post another picture with your "desired" result?

Comment: I built this fiddle, what is it that is not workin? https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/hfqsecdz/

Comment: if its inheriting some css from your template. , add more detail of your css

Answer (score 0):

My result should look like this
[image]

but its looking like below.. its inheriting some css from my template

[image]

Comment: You're talking about the template again, but without showing us what's in it.

Answer (score 0):

The code on its own is working. You can use developer tools in chrome or Firefox to find what other CSS from the template is causing the issue.

Look for *job-search-job-title* class and see what is being added from the template.

or try the below code:

```
.job-search-job-title { width: 65%; margin-top: 0em !important; padding-top: 0em !important;  }
```

Cheers